# Display HTML page response in react js

Tags: reactjs, iframe

How to display the html page returned by the server in react-js. I have tried it with iframe by giving the url in src attribute and it is working.

```
<iframe title="html page" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/htmlpage/?name=test" sandbox="allow-same-origin"></iframe>
```

But i don't want to access it that way, instead the request has to be made using axios and the response should be displayed.

Below is the code i tried, which makes a request to the endpoint and the html page is received. displaying it in iframe shows empty area.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Table.css";
import { Button } from "./Button";
import axios from "axios";

class Tables extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      report: false,
      html_resp: "",
    };
    this.viewhtml = this.viewhtml.bind(this);
  }

  viewhtml() {
    var self = this;
    this.setState({ report: true });
    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/htmlpage/",
      params: {
        name: "test",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        self.setState({ html_resp: response.data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { report, html_resp } = this.state;

    const report_view = report ? (
      <div className="report">
        <iframe
          title="html page"
          src={html_resp}
          scrolling="yes"
          height="100%"
          width="100%"
          sandbox="allow-same-origin"
        ></iframe>
      </div>
    ) : null;

    return (
      <>
        <div className="html report">
          <Button
            buttonStyle="btn--secondary"
            buttonSize="btn--small--opt"
            onClick={this.viewhtml}
          >
            View HTML Page
          </Button>
        </div>
        {report_view} {/* show the html page returned by server here */}
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Tables;
```

It would be a great help if somebody could guide me here. I'm in the process of learning react

Answer (score 0):

Updated code, you just send the iframe component as string to `IFrameComponent` and it will render it. Hope it works and let me know.

```
 import { IFrameComponent } from './IFrameComponent';
  ...
 render() {
    const { html_resp } = this.state;

    const iframeStr = html_resp ? `<iframe title="html_page" src={html_resp} 
                               scrolling="yes" height="100%" width="100%"
                               sandbox="allow-same-origin">
                               </iframe>` : null;        

    return (
      <>
        <div className="html report">
          <Button
            buttonStyle="btn--secondary"
            buttonSize="btn--small--opt"
            onClick={this.viewhtml}
          >
            View HTML Page
          </Button>
        </div>
        { html_resp && <IFrameComponent iframe={iframeStr}/> }
      </>
    );
  }
```

Create new React Component

```
import React from 'react';

export class IFrameComponent extends React.Component<{iframe:string},{}>{
   public iframe = () => {
      return {
        __html: this.props.iframe
      }
    }
  
   public render = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ this.iframe() } />
        </div>
      );
    }
 
  }
```

Comment: ,tried it. but it prints the html instead of displaying the page

Comment: Yes, it is receiving the correct response. using the above code it display the whole html content in p tag instead of rendering it as html page

Comment: nope. still it is showing empty area. Is this the correct way to render in iframe? like by saving the response html content to state variable and using it inside iframe?

Comment: still no changes. can you please give some insight on this please : is this the correct way to render in iframe? like by saving the response html content to state variable and using it inside iframe?

Comment: @liquiddeath Read [this](https://iframely.com/docs/reactjs)

Comment: @liquiddeath Did you check my updated answer?

Comment: Nope, i was able to get it work with the code i posted in question, by changing src to srcdoc. But the problem is it takes too much time to render the contents in iframe. I believe in the above answer also it should be changed to srcdoc, i will try this bcs i need a way to display the contents faster

Comment: @liquiddeath try without changing the `src` but if it doesn't work then change it.